# iOS crash below iOS9.3 with SIGSEGV, different Crash Log

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault, crash-log

Many crashes happened below the iOS9.3 (which means devices with iOS10 are OK)..
The crash logs seem to show that it's not a problem about API that can only be used below iOS 9.3 .
But I have no idea about the crash logs. ( I'm sorry ...for I just start to study iOS development for only 2 month ) 
Could you please help me analyze the crash logs ? 
Really Thanks !

[crash log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Yqr.jpg)

[crash log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAGC2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

AXE_BAD_ACCESS - this is problem with memory. One of function tried to use variable which already released. I think you need to check use your TableView and cells for this table.

Also to find problem with memory you can try to use [zombies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Used to have the similar strange crashes in my app. And only in production, when testing from TestFlight. Building on device with ios 9 caused no problems.
Maybe it sounds strange, but try to convert all images you use in app to images with included sRGB color profile. For me it helped.